# data.frame tries to assign variable name as tag instead of variable content?

Tags: r

I'm trying to assign variable content to a data.frame column name as well as a dataset with the following argument below.

data.frame(tag = value)

But for some reasons it's assigning the variable name as the tag instead of the variable contents?

```
> dataset_name
[1] "Dataset_1"

> dataset
  [1]  27.966  55.932  39.346  63.680  82.446

data <- data.frame(dataset_name = dataset)

> data
    dataset_name
1         27.966
2         55.932
3         39.346
4         63.680
5         82.446
```

This is the desired output

```
> data
    Dataset_1
1      27.966
2      55.932
3      39.346
4      63.680
5      82.446
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setNames`

```
setNames(data.frame(dataset), dataset_name)
```

---

We can also use some non-standard evaluation

```
tibble(!!dataset_name := dataset)
```

Comment: @RonakShah names(dataset) <- dataset_name, I guess this should also do, as the user is just changing field name.

Comment: @Neel Not exactly, from the question, it seems `dataset` is a vector. For example,  `dataset <- 1:10`, `dataset_name <- "any_name"` and if you do `names(dataset) <- dataset_name` it doesn't give expected output

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks, didn't notice dataset is vector.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `set_names` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setnames(data.table(dataset), dataset_name)
```